# Oracle SQL exclude specific type multiple rows select with exact two rows

Tags: sql, oracle, conditional-aggregation

I am trying to write oracle sql to select all emplids from table ABC 
excluding the emplids with three specific roles. example is as follows - 

TABLE1= ABC

EMPLID        ROLE
______________________
111                
Apple
111                 
Mango
111                 
Red_Apple
222                 
Apple
222                 
Orange
222                 
Red_Mango
222                 
Banana
333                 
Apple
333                 
Orange
444                 
Apple
444                 
Mango
444                 
Red_Mango
555                 
Grapes
666                 
Orange
666                 
Grapes
666                 
Blueberry

TABLE2 = DETAILS

EMPLID     NAME     EMAIL
__________________________________
111            John         
info@email.com
222            Erica        
info@email.com
and so on....

Basically, in above example since Apple, Mango, and Red% are the three roles 
that needs to be excluded. The sql should return EMPLID and NAME for 
222,333,555,and 666. It should exclude 111 and 444

I tried creating sub selects but still not working.`enter code here`. Any advice or help is 
highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT t1.EMPLID,
       t1.NAME,
       t1.EMAIL
FROM DETAILS t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT EMPLID
    FROM ABC
    GROUP BY EMPLID
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN ROLE = 'Apple' OR ROLE = 'Mango' OR ROLE LIKE 'Red%'
                    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) < 3
) t2
    ON t1.EMPLID = t2.EMPLID
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Will test for all scenarios now :-)

Comment: Basically, the following row must be included as well - 

777, Apple, Red_Apple,  Mango, Avocado, Lime

Exclude Emplid with only three lines with Apple, Mango, Red%